# List linux processes having windows

Tags: linux, xorg, ps

How can I list linux processes (like `ps aux`) but only those having X11 windows?

I guess there must be some simple connection (like always in linux) between the processes and the X server. Is it exposed to `lsof` ?

Answer (score 4):

> xwininfo -tree -root | grep -v "has no name" | grep -v child

It's a bit of a different approach than what you requested: instead of listing processes, it lists windows.  If you're looking for a list of process ID numbers, this doesn't accomplish the task.  If you're looking for a list of what's running, this does.

Obviously, this approach will not show you the name of any program that has "child" as part of its name.  Still, if you're looking for a quick and easy option that will serve most purposes, this may be one.

Oh, and by the way, there are a number of other [options to "xwininfo"](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/xwininfo.1.xhtml), such as being able to specify the name of just one window (instead of specifying the "root" window).

Comment: Additionally, you can use `xlsclients` command which has similar functionality. If you need X11 window ids converted to PIDs, take a look at the NetWM (aka EWMH) specification. Compliant clients may set `_NET_WM_PID` Atom, which can be read using `xprop` utility provided you know the window id.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean. Most likely, the command you wish to use is

```
    ps alx | grep pts
```

You will need the `long` flag to `ps` to display the eleventh column, which identifies a process's terminal, if any.

However, you can also see the same info in a different format, with `pstree` which ...

> pstree  shows  running  processes  as  a tree.  The tree is rooted at either pid or init if pid is omitted.

With this, you can search for the Desktop Manager (kdm, in my case) and then see from this all processes which *descend* from this, including those you begin yourself like an ssh connection. If you use the `-p` flag, you will be given the process numbers,

```
      ├─konsole(2716)─┬─bash(2739)───ssh(8328)
                      │               └─{konsole}(2738)
```

which allows you to check that the process number for the `ssh` process is the same as in the output of `ps alx`. But this does **not** display, AFAIK, the tty the command was issued in.